# How to data from yii2-widget-select2

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2

This is my first time use of yii framework and try to use kratik widget in view.
In _form.php,

```
$data = [
"a" => "Apple",
"b" => "Banana",
"c" => "coconut",
];

$form->field($model, 'tag[]')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $data,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'choose category', 'multiple' => true],
        'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => true,
        'tokenSeparators' => [',', ' '],
        'maximumInputLength' => 10
        ],
    ])->label('Select Category'); ?>
```

I would like to get selected data from controller. Here is my controller.php,

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new ChildData();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $userId = Yii::$app->user->getId();
        $model->user_id= $userId;
        $model->fruit=json_encode($model->tag);
        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }   
}
```

So, In Child table, I set fruit attribute as varchar(255). After running code,I selected all tags of fruits data from kartik widget but it only saved '[]' in fruit attribute.

Thus, I would like to know how to take data from kartik select2 in controller.php? What type of data does kartik select2 return? and how to pass selected data to view.php? Please feel free to guide me about using kartik widgets.
Thank you.

Comment: You can dump Yii::$app->request->post() and check if there is data submitted. If there is data for 'tag' then check if you have rule for 'tag' in ChildData model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a custom field declared in the model for the `tag` that you are using to populate the `Select2`. As you are not using the same field to load the model inside  you `actionCreate` on this line.

```
$model->fruit=json_encode($model->tag);
```

To use he `Select2` Single Or Multiple mode you don't need to provide the input name as an array i-e just use `tag`

```
$form->field($model, 'tag')
```

Change your create action to following so that you get validation errors if any.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new ChildData();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $userId = Yii::$app->user->getId();
        $model->user_id= $userId;
        $model->fruit=json_encode($model->tag);
        if($model->save()){
          return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } 

    } 
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);

}
```

Also can you please share your `model` code. There must be a rule defined for tag else it won't be populated. And if it is not a database field, you'll have to define a custom attribute within model i-e

```
public $tag;
```

Add a rule for `tag` attribute. example below

```
[['tag'], 'safe']
```

`$model->load($data)` populates only those attributes which have a rule defined.

Comment: Here is my Model class,

public $tag=[];
public function rules()
{
 return [
[['user_id'], 'integer'],
[['fruit'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
[['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],];
}
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('frontend/child_data', 'ID'),
            'user_id' => Yii::t('frontend/child_data', 'User ID'),
            'fruit' => Yii::t('frontend/child_data', 'Fruit'),
        ];
    }

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: It is work!!! I added rules for $tag in model as you mentioned above. Now selected data from select2 is saved in database. Thank you so much for help @IrfanAshraf.